# JS array push error in IE only

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following script, which essentially extracts each value from the "data" array being passed and returns json value.

```
 function parsejson(data) {
           var temp2 = new Array();

           if (data) {
               $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                   vproductid = data[i].productid;
                   vproductname = data[i].product_name;
                   vexpirydt = data[i].expiry;

                   temp2.push({vproductid,vproductname,vexpirydt});

               }); 

               console.log([temp2]);
               return [temp2];
           }
       }
```

So in this case "data" within my console log comes back as:

> Array [ Object, Object ]

Which contains the following objects -> values, etc, and in some instances my "expiry" date value is blank space, but still appears to work properly in Firefox and Chrome.

[image: Array Details]

The issues seems to be exclusively with IE 11 in my case.... I keep getting the following Error in IE only which ties back to the "push" to append to my array somehow.  I don't know if it's a syntax error or the way in which I'm trying to append to my array, but obviously I'm doing something wrong.  My intention is simply to return a second array in json format, so might be a simpler way.

> SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'

Comment: You're using new syntax features in an old browser. This is what transpilers are built to handle.

Comment: I could be blind but I don't see any ES2015 in his code.

Comment: @ChipDean: `temp2.push({vproductid,vproductname,vexpirydt});` A legacy compatible syntax would be to provide explicit property names and values: `temp2.push({vproductid:vproductid, vproductname:vproductname, vexpirydt:vexpirydt});`

Comment: Push is not ES2015. That has always been around.

Comment: Yep, since 3rd edition javascript. Just double checked.

Comment: @ChipDean: Look more closely.

Comment: Ah good catch :)

Comment: @denisb: If `data` is an Array, you can do this more cleanly with `.map()`... `var temp2 = data.map(function(o) { return {vproductid:o.productid, vproductname:o.product_name, vexpirydt:o.expiry} })`

Comment: @squint:  Thank you for the response, I'm trying to get a grasp on how the map() function works, so would the above setting of temp2 represent the append of values to my array?  I'm not familiar with "map()", so will try to find some examples on how it works.  Thanks again!

Comment: @denisb: You've probably figured it out by now, but `.map()` simply creates a new array of the same length of the original, populated with the return value of the callback function, which gets invoked on each index of the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments provide the answear to IE error, here is a sample code that will work on IE and Chrome:

```
function parsejson(data) {
    var temp2 = []; // this syntax might be prefered to create a new array

    if (data) {
        temp2 = data.map(function(element) { 
            return {
                vproductid: element.productid,
                vproductname: element.product_name,
                vexpirydt: element.expiry
            };
        });
    }
    console.log(temp2);
    return temp2;
}

var sampleData = [{
    productid: 1,
    product_name: 'a',
    expiry: 'Today',
    someThingelse: '',
}, {
    productid: 2,
    product_name: 'b',
    expiry: 'Today',
    someThingelse: '',
}, {
    productid: 3,
    product_name: 'c',
    expiry: 'Today',
    someThingelse: '',
}];


parsejson(sampleData);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!   Only minor tweak is to return temp2 within square brackets for my own display purposes, but it works!!   Thanks again!